# Desktop inside desktop How can i delete it?

Tags: desktop

[image]Hi Please refer the below image for reference. It showing one more dektop, I need to remove it.

Comment: Did you install Nautilus or some program like this? In this case uninstall it and it will be fine

Comment: Please, mark my answer as solved

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Nautilus or some program like this, you just have to uninstall it.